How to disable next button of the vue-form-wizard? or override it with custom button and hide only the next button
I am new to vue js, I am using this vue-form-wizard and I am not sure if there is a way to disable the next button by some conditions, so depends on the conditions will enable or disable the button
 <form-wizard
        title=""
        subtitle=""
        color="#03608E"
        :nextButtonText="__('Next')"
        :backButtonText="__('Back')"
        :finishButtonText="__('Finish')"
        @on-validate="handleValidation"
        @on-error="handleErrorMessage"
        @on-complete="finish"
        transition="fadeIn"
        ref="wizard"
    >

Or at least if there is a way to remove or hide the next button only ?
Is it the only way to do this to hide both buttons and add custom buttons for this ??
Please tell me the better way, thanks in advance

vue-form-wizard isn't an established tag, so you'll need to be more specific about what library this is referring to, i.e. provide a link. Though if it's not very popular you'll likely find more success directly asking the library author/community if there happens to be a public github or via other contact method.

@yoduh I added the link of the library, it seems popular

Hmm, the project's last official release was 2018 and has been archived on github since last year.  I'm surprised it works at all in a Vue 3 project since it was never updated to work with anything other than Vue 2.  It may still be getting occasional downloads on NPM but it's officially a deprecated and abandoned library.  I would not expect any support for this.  If that's a requirement for you, I would look for an alternative!
